Haskell: Rigid type binding
The following code works as expected:
data Test a = Test {
    sample    :: [a],
    underflow :: a,
    width     :: a,
    bounds    :: Int -> a
}

test :: Num a => [a] -> a -> a -> Test a
test sample underflow width = Test {
    sample,
    underflow,
    width,
    bounds
}
    where
        -- bounds :: Int -> a
        bounds 0 = underflow
        bounds i = width + bounds (i - 1)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ map (bounds t) [1..10]
    where t = test [1..6] 3 5

However, it fails to compile when I uncomment the line "bounds :: Int -> a", because apparently the "a" in the commented line is a different "a" as the "a" in the signature of "test".
How can I refer from within the where clause to a type from the functions signature?
Or how can I bind a type to be the same as the original "a" (Not sure if the wording of "type" and "binding" are correct)?

Use scoped type variables and an explicit forall a as in test :: forall a . Num a => [a] -> a -> a -> Test a.
